# MYSql Stored Procedure, DateTime value not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE GetWinners(IN Number INTEGER , IN Table_Name VarChar(7)) 
BEGIN 
 SET @t1 = CONCAT('Select * FROM ', Table_Name, ' Where number = ', Number, ' && active = true && dateAndTime < 2015-02-10');
 PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
 EXECUTE stmt3;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
END // 
DELIMITER ;
```

dateAndTime is a column where I store DateTime values.
I can't understand why with `&& dateAndTime < 2015-02-10'`, the query returns no results.

If I remove `&& dateAndTime < 2015-02-10'`, then some results are returned.
This happens even though I have DateTime value lower than 2015-02-10 in the columns.

Answer (score 1):

This most probably due to your date format, the time is added to the date but due to your preferences in mysql, it only shows the date without time.
Use `trim` or `trunc` to remove the time.

```
TRUNC(dateAndTime) < TO_DATE('2015-02-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: nop Try it with 2016-12-20 12:27:19 and the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Surround your DateTime in single quotes

```
SET @t1 = CONCAT('Select * FROM ', Table_Name, ' Where number = ', Number, ' && active = true && dateAndTime < '2015-02-10'');
```

Comment: If I do                                                                                                      Select * FROM Table_Name where number = 111 && active = true && dateAndTime < '2016-01-20'; It works, but with CONCAT single qoutes not working :(

Comment: reading through MYSQL reference manual [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)                      OK, this QUOTE('2016-12-20 12:27:19') does the trick - thanks